# landscape images from photo library swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, landscape, photo-gallery

I am making landscape app, I need to pick only landscape photos from the Photo Library, How do I fetch photos only in landscape?

Answer (score 0):

Filter the images using the `image.imageOrientation` property.

UIImageOrientation ref - [Here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimageorientation)

You can use `PHAsset` class to fetch all the images with required specification by using predicate.And then filter the images based on the `image.imageOrientation`

Eg:-

```
let options = PHFetchOptions()    
options.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]

var images = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: options)
```

PHClass - [Ref](https://developer.apple.com/reference/photos/phasset)

Comment: First of all thanks means, I need to fetch all images from photo library and then check its orientation.

Comment: yes..Are you using PHAsset class to get images or UIIMagePickerController?

Comment: PHAsset does not provide any predicate or subtype to show image picker only landscape photos ?, I need to create custom picker

Comment: Yes...there is no predicate to identify the image orientation.

Comment: Using custom picker will you able to access multiple images at same time?

Comment: Or you can use "pixelWidth" and "pixelHeight" properties to identify the orientation by comparing the height and width.

Answer (score 0):

you need get size image . with > height ==> it is landscape